# How to test nomological validity with lavaan?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, validity

in my understanding, I need to test nomological validity with SEM. But what exactly should I look at in e.g. summary(fit1, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)?

Code for reference:

```
model1 <- 'O  =~ o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + o5
T  =~  t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
G =~ g1 + g2 + g3
P =~ p1 + p2 + p3
P ~ O + T + G'

fit1 <- sem(model1, data=data)
```

Comment: Please specify what aggregate group characteristic may or may not be different at the individual level.  Also, generally MLM is used to assess nomological validity by showing insignificant intra-individual variation (this can be done in the SEM framework...but that is not necessary).

Comment: All characteristics are on individual level.

Comment: If you are suggesting that there all of the responses demonstrate unique patterns for each individual, then ¿what do you mean by nomological validity?

Comment: Sorry, I understood you wrongly. The O, T and G are the responses while P is an objective measure (I made a mistake in the code here too). O, T, G are supposed to somehow predict P.